# How to interpret bus timetables of Bergamo, Italy?

Tags: buses, italy, bergamo

I'm using this: https://www.atb.bergamo.it/en/google-transit

And I'm completely lost. I just discovered that buses have their "subnumbers" so line 6 has 6A, 6B, 6C and 6 - Stezzano, ok that's fine, but I'm looking at a timetable for bus 6 for example: https://www.atb.bergamo.it/en/atb-network/routes-and-timetables and how should I interpret these tables? I mean, I can see on top all kind of "sixes" that are running around and I have timetables but I don't see how any of these tables relate to any specific "six". How should I read these tables to extract the information: at which times 6B departures Porta Nuova - for example?

Comment: I think this timetable isn't supposed to give you this information. Instead its designed to help you get from Porta Nuova to your destination, this is the case as the routes are very similar (see the diagram at the top). So instead use the timetable to look for continuous services (ie. They are one column) between Porta Nuova and your destination, and accept that it will be a 6x bus which should appear.

Comment: The problem is, that the Stezzano Ovest (6B) is quite far away from Stezzano Est (6C), it could be almost 1,5km of walking from one to the second, and you would have to know the way. Does this timetable assume that "enter the 6, and you will go into the general direction of your destination, you might be off by quite a distance though"? But even that seems not to be the case, because bus 1, dependently on the "subnumber" can go to completely different parts of the city (and one of the destinations is the airport - the place in which you pretty much have to be on time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's implicit in the timetables. Took me a while to figure it, too, and I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

If you look at the beginning of the timetable document, for each bus line it states all the "sublines" and where they go, and notice that each subline has a different final destination or path than the others subline.

Let's take as an example the 6C line, which start from San Colombano and stop at Stezzano Est. It's not listed explicitly in the timetable (welcome to Italy), but check the timetable row for Stezzano Est and notice that only a few columns have the time of arrival for it **and** the leaving time from San Colombano: those are your 6C buses. For example, on the summer timetables, the 7.12 from San Colombano is a 6C.

Comment: Oooh, that makes sense. What adds to confusion is that in their trip planner all these buses are named "6" and to find out which "6" it is, you have to look at the route details (and there can be 6 without a letter also, so you can easily wrongly assume that it's that one). This has to be one of the most confusing timetable/trip planner I have ever seen, but now I got it, thanks :) .

Comment: You are welcome. And yes, it's confusing, but it wouldn't be Italy otherwise.